# MATLAB run script with input from other script

Tags: matlab

I cannot be difficult, but I cannot seem to find the solution to this question. I have a script (`Main.m`) that runs through a couple of other scripts. If these scripts take their 'inputs' from the workspace, all goes fine. However, one of the scripts I'd like to run/evaluate from `Main.m` has to be called as `script input`, with input a string. I have saved the input-string in a variable `id`. Let's say the script is called `SCRIPT` and the input is `IN`, then `id = 'IN'`.

I would like to tell MATLAB (in the `Main.m`-script) to run `SCRIPT id`, where `id` is to be replaced by the value I have set to `id`.

Thanks for all help and information (or for telling me that this is impossible)!

Comment: What about `SCRIPT(id)` using paranthesis? Btw. that would be a function then, not a script. I think you are getting confused about the fact, that you can call a function by `f id`, but then id is treated as a string literal and not a variable. Use `f(id)` to have id treated as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

`SCRIPT(id)` did the trick! Thanks!